# Can't remove view from root view

Tags: android, android-view, rootview

i add the view to the `rootview` in that way

```
private RelativeLayout addThisView;
private View rootView;

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
addThisView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_temp_cover, null, false);
if(rootView instanceof FrameLayout){
     ((FrameLayout)rootView).addView(addThisView);
}
```

trying to remove view from root view

```
/* remove view from the root view start */

rootView = ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
RelativeLayout loadingTempCoverRelative =(RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadingTempCoverRelative);

if(loadingTempCoverRelative!=null){
    if(rootView instanceof FrameLayout){
        ((FrameLayout)rootView).removeView(loadingTempCoverRelative);
    }
}

/* remove view from the root view end */
```

and then when i check the `loadingTempCover` is exist (below codes). it is still exist..
i debugged and see; when reach and complete the `removeView()` function it doesn't effect anything. still i can see the `loadingTempCover` layout in `rootview`. i couldn't understand where am i doing wrong..

```
rootView = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
RelativeLayout loadingTempCoverRelative =(RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadingTempCoverRelative);

if(loadingTempCoverRelative!=null){ 
    loadingTempCoverRelative.setVisibility(loadingTempCoverRelative.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the parent directly by the view:

```
rootView = ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
RelativeLayout loadingTempCoverRelative =(RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadingTempCoverRelative);

ViewGroup parent = loadingTempCoverRelative.getParent();

if(loadingTempCoverRelative!=null){
    if(rootView instanceof FrameLayout && parent != null){
        parent.removeView(loadingTempCoverRelative);
    }
}
```

You should test the condition `if(rootView instanceof FrameLayout)` as well, the issue is maybe here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. it is not relevant with if condition or getParent. Android studio causes this problem. I rebuild the project and problem is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
((ViewGroup) rootView.getParent()).removeView(namebar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Captain here. I had the same problem with `animateLayoutChanges` options and need to say, that it's possible to have this issue. Furthermore, somehow there is no issues with **Android 10 Q**.

But for all other cases, it's not possible to remove view inside parent with `animateLayoutChanges`. It's like make sense, because this view required by parent to finish animate. But any delay will not help, `View` will stay with parent after delay too.